# Surface area of inverse functions

Tags: calculus, integration, inverse, curves, surface-integrals

I was wondering if the area of a curve rotated about the x-axis could be found by rotating the inverse curve about the y-axis because I have to find the the area by rotating $x = \frac{1}{4} y^2  - \frac{1}{2} \ln(y)$

and it seems like this would be much easier to do about the y-axis because than I don't have to find $y(x)$. Is this a correct way of solving this?

Comment: Not totally sure what you're asking, but (i) Surface area depends only on geometry, not coordinate systems, so in a sense the answer is _yes_; (ii) This looks unlikely to help in your situation; (iii) If you just calculate the area integral, $1 + (dx/dy)^{2}$ is a perfect square.

Comment: In general, rotating a curve about the $x$ and $y$ axes gives totally different volumes and surface areas. But you $can$ rotate the inverse curve about the $x$ axis.